# problemas al enviar datos a un php en 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql, game

estoy intentando crear una conexión desde mi aplicación de game maker hacia un php alojado en 000webhost el php en cuestión simplemente recibe los datos de un http_post proveniente de game maker y lo inserta en una base de datos, este código funcionaba perfectamente en un host llamado alter vista pero cuando lo intente migrar a 000webhost me dejo de funcionar por completo incluso con algunas advertencias de por medio lo cual es extraño dado que ambos servicios usan php 8.2.

el error que me sale al correr el php es:

`Notice: Undefined index: secret_key in /storage/ssd5/694/21785694/public_html/addscore.php on line 11`

y no se reciben los datos desde game maker hacia el php en la web.

este es el código php alojado en 000webhost

```
   // conectar con la base de datos
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxx');
$secret_key = "xxxxxxx";

   
   // compara la contraseña enviada desde game maker con la registrada en el php
   
  
   if ($secret_key == $_POST['secret_key'])
   {
 // prepara la inserción 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO OnlineHighscores VALUES (NULL,:name, :score) 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   `score` = IF (VALUES(`score`) > `score`, VALUES(`score`), `score`) ;";
       $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(':score', $score, PDO::PARAM_INT);

       // obtiene los datos del http_post desde game maker
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $score = $_POST['score'];

       // ejecuta el comando
       $stmt->execute();
       echo '1';
   }
   else
   {
       ;
        echo "Conectado";
   }






?>
```

este código es de un proyecto ejemplo para subir datos en este caso un sistema de leaderboard para game maker que obtuve de un tutorial y que modifique un poco para lo que necesitaba.

y aqui esta el codigo en game maker que envia los datos

```
// ofusca el nombre en base64 encode 
 var name = url_encode(base64_encode(string(argument0)));
//formula el orden de los valores name y score
    var args = "name="+name+"&score="+string(argument1)+"&secret_key=xxxxxx";
// finalmente hace el http_post hacia la direccion donde esta el php
  http_post_string("http://superchonkyjumpers.000webhostapp.com/addscore.php", args);
```

como mencione antes este codigo funcionaba sin errores en altervista pero queria probar otro host y fue donde empezaron los problemas.

gracias por leer y agradezco la ayuda! saludos

Comment: Has probado con otra aplicación (por ej:postman) a enviar una petición y ver si el servidor contesta bien?

Comment: gracias por responder!, parece que logre arreglarlo todo el problema era en la configuración de la base de datos lo tenia configurado  Cotejamiento de la conexión al servidor lo tenia mal para aquello que usen este código se debe poner esa opción en utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci